# Radio Buttons won't display properly

Tags: java, radio-button, jpanel

I am just learning radio buttons, and thought I had finally gotten it since it compiled fine. But when I try to run the program, this error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1090)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:410)
at ActionFrame.makeComponents(ActionFrame.java:43)
at ActionFrame.<init>(ActionFrame.java:20)
at ActionFrame.main(ActionFrame.java:80)
```

I don't know know what I'm doing wrong, so if you could just point me in the right direction maybe? Or explain to me why what I am doing is wrong?

```
public class ActionFrame extends JFrame {
JLabel messageLabel;
JRadioButton rb1;
JRadioButton rb2;
JRadioButton rb3;
JRadioButton rb4;
String a = "Football";
String b = "Basketball";
String c = "Baseball";
String d = "Hockey";

public ActionFrame() {
  setTitle("Favorite Sports");
  setSize (400,200);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(
     JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

  JPanel myStuff = makeComponents();
  add(myStuff);
  setVisible(true);
}

private JPanel makeComponents() {
  JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();

  messageLabel = new JLabel("Select your favorite sport: ");

  rb1 = new JRadioButton(a, true);
  rb1 = new JRadioButton(b);
  rb1 = new JRadioButton(c);
  rb1 = new JRadioButton(d);

  ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

  group.add(rb1);
  group.add(rb2);
  group.add(rb3);
  group.add(rb4);

  myPanel.add(rb1);
  myPanel.add(rb2);
  myPanel.add(rb3);
  myPanel.add(rb4);

  rb1.addActionListener( new BList() );
  rb2.addActionListener( new BList() );
  rb3.addActionListener( new BList() );
  rb4.addActionListener( new BList() );

  myPanel.add(messageLabel);

  return myPanel;
}

private class BList implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

     if(e.getSource() == rb1){
        System.out.println("Your favorite sport is " + a +".");
     }

     else if(e.getSource() == rb2){
        System.out.println("Your favorite sport is " + b +".");
     }

     else if(e.getSource() == rb3){
        System.out.println("Your favorite sport is " + c +".");
     }

     else if(e.getSource() == rb4){
        System.out.println("Your favorite sport is " + d +".");
     }

  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  new ActionFrame();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not:

```
  rb1 = new JRadioButton(a, true);
  rb1 = new JRadioButton(b);
  rb1 = new JRadioButton(c);
  rb1 = new JRadioButton(d);
```

But:

```
  rb1 = new JRadioButton(a, true);
  rb2 = new JRadioButton(b);
  rb3 = new JRadioButton(c);
  rb4 = new JRadioButton(d);
```

Oops.

The key here is not your error, shoot we all make similar errors. The key is to learn how to debug an NPE. When you get one, check the line that throws the exception, find out which variable is null and look back to try to solve it. ***That*** is the key.

Comment: @user2877117: nah, you're not an idiot; you just haven't learned to debug an NPE. Please read my edit.

Answer (score 2):

You've named all your radiobuttons `rb1` so the other components are never initialized

```
rb1 = new JRadioButton(a, true);
rb2 = new JRadioButton(b);
rb3 = new JRadioButton(c);
rb4 = new JRadioButton(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
  rb1 = new JRadioButton(a, true);
  rb1 = new JRadioButton(b);
  rb1 = new JRadioButton(c);
  rb1 = new JRadioButton(d);
```

into

```
  rb1 = new JRadioButton(a, true);
  rb2 = new JRadioButton(b);
  rb3 = new JRadioButton(c);
  rb4 = new JRadioButton(d);
```

original code(with changings)

```
public class ActionFrame extends JFrame {
JLabel messageLabel;
JRadioButton rb1;
JRadioButton rb2;
JRadioButton rb3;
JRadioButton rb4;
String a = "Football";
String b = "Basketball";
String c = "Baseball";
String d = "Hockey";

public ActionFrame() {
  setTitle("Favorite Sports");
  setSize (400,200);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(
     JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

  JPanel myStuff = makeComponents();
  add(myStuff);
  setVisible(true);
}

private JPanel makeComponents() {
  JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();

  messageLabel = new JLabel("Select your favorite sport: ");

/// changes are here...
  rb1 = new JRadioButton(a, true);
  rb2 = new JRadioButton(b);
  rb3 = new JRadioButton(c);
  rb4 = new JRadioButton(d);

  ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

  group.add(rb1);
  group.add(rb2);
  group.add(rb3);
  group.add(rb4);

  myPanel.add(rb1);
  myPanel.add(rb2);
  myPanel.add(rb3);
  myPanel.add(rb4);

  rb1.addActionListener( new BList() );
  rb2.addActionListener( new BList() );
  rb3.addActionListener( new BList() );
  rb4.addActionListener( new BList() );

  myPanel.add(messageLabel);

  return myPanel;
}

private class BList implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

     if(e.getSource() == rb1){
        System.out.println("Your favorite sport is " + a +".");
     }

     else if(e.getSource() == rb2){
        System.out.println("Your favorite sport is " + b +".");
     }

     else if(e.getSource() == rb3){
        System.out.println("Your favorite sport is " + c +".");
     }

     else if(e.getSource() == rb4){
        System.out.println("Your favorite sport is " + d +".");
     }

  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  new ActionFrame();
}
}
```